# How to limit JSON to MYSQL export to top 10K lines?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using a JSON to MYSQL convert PHP code that reads the data from a JSON feed. Below is my code. The problem I am running into is that JSON feed is like 3 Million lines. I just want to pick the top 10K lines and then export it to MYSQL. How to achieve that in below code?

```
<?php
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 0);

require_once 'db_connect.php';

/* DEFINE TABLE NAME AND SOURCE URL HERE */
$str_tbl_name   = 'table_name';
$str_source_url = 'https://www.json-feed.com/example';

/* FETCH DATA FROM RESOURCE LINK */
$str_source_content = file_get_contents($str_source_url);
$arr_data           = json_decode($str_source_content);

$str_date_time  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$str_start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arr_data->meta->start_date));
$str_end_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arr_data->meta->end_date));
$arr_value_sql  = [];
foreach ($arr_data->data as $data) {
    /* DATA CLEANSING */
    $data->source_subregion        = !empty($data->source_subregion) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_subregion) : null;
    $data->source_country_code     = !empty($data->source_country_code) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_country_code) : null;
    $str_input_name                = !empty($data->metadata->search_name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->metadata->search_name) : null;
    $data->document_url            = !empty($data->document_url) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_url) : null;
    $str_document_tags             = !empty((array) $data->document_tags) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(serialize($data->document_tags)) : null;
    $data->document_sentiment      = !empty($data->document_sentiment) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_sentiment) : null;
    $data->source_name             = !empty($data->source_name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_name) : null;
    $data->document_publish_date   = !empty($data->document_publish_date) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_publish_date) : null;
    $str_document_matched_keywords = !empty((array) $data->document_matched_keywords) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(implode(',', $data->document_matched_keywords)) : null;
    $data->document_language_code  = !empty($data->document_language_code) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_language_code) : null;
    $str_document_key_phrases      = !empty((array) $data->document_key_phrases) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(implode(',', $data->document_key_phrases)) : null;
    $data->document_hit_sentence   = !empty($data->document_hit_sentence) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_hit_sentence) : null;
    $data->document_hidden         = ($data->document_hidden === true) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    $str_document_authors          = !empty($data->document_authors[0]->name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_authors[0]->name) : null;
    $data->document_city           = !empty($data->document_city) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_city) : null;

    $str_value_sql = " ("
            . "'{$data->document_publish_date}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_url}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_name}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_authors}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_country_code}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_subregion}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_language_code}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_reach}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_ave}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_sentiment}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_key_phrases}'"
            . ", '{$str_input_name}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_matched_keywords}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_city}'"
            . ")";
    array_push($arr_value_sql, $str_value_sql);
}
```

Comment: Use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: But where do I mention the number 10k?

Comment: It'll depend on how the `data` object is keyed, but if it's numeric `for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) { $data = $arr_data->data[$i]; ...`. Otherwise you can use the counter approach suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter or the array indices and break from the `foreach` after getting the desired number of rows.

Counter:

```
$counter=0;
$values=[];
foreach($arr_data->data as $data){
    array_push($values, ...);
    if($counter++>=10000)
        break;
}
//Insert rows
```

Array Keys(assuming sequential array):

```
foreach($arr_data->data as $key=>$data){
    if($key>=10000)
        break;
    array_push($values, ...);
}
//Insert rows
```

Comment: Can you show me the edit that will be done in my code for the counter as i cannot use Keys?

Comment: Is your array sequential? If so, literally add `$key=>` before `$data` in your `foreach` and add `if($key>=10000) break;` in the first line of the `foreach`. That's it.

Comment: Nope the counter does not help I tried it using 100 it did not work it is pulling the whole data and running out of memory

Comment: So the issue is running out of memory. I assume this is just the content of the JSON feed? In other words, if you take out everything after your `json_decode`, does it still fail? If so, you'll have to read the content incrementally rather than all at once. You may not be able to reasonably do this depending on your feed API(does it provide any parameters?). You can't parse partial JSON. This may be a case for just increasing the memory limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`for loop`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) instead of `foreach`.

If the problem is that you are running out of memory and cannot paginate the results at the API, but can decode the whole thing, you can try running a first pass to delete the unneeded elements and free memory and then process normally.

```
// Delete unwanted elements
for($i=10000; $i<count($arr_data->data); $i++) { 
    unset($arr_data->data[$i]);
}

foreach ($arr_data->data as $data) {
    // Your old loop
}
```